# How do I disable re-direct after adding a new product on Dokan Vendor Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, wordpress-shortcode

Recently I made a custom shortcode that displays the Dokan "Add Product" form, but now every time I add a new product I get redirected to the Product edit page in the Dokan dashboard. My php skills are very limited as this is the 1st time iv'e ever done any coding but I get stuff fast.

Can someone help me with this issue?

This is the end of the code that the shortcode displays (after the submit button).

```
 </form>

            <?php } else { ?>

                <?php dokan_seller_not_enabled_notice(); ?>

            <?php } ?>

        <?php } else { ?>

            <?php do_action( 'dokan_can_post_notice' ); ?>

        <?php } ?>
    </div>

    <?php

        /**
         *  dokan_after_new_product_inside_content_area hook
         *
         *  @since 2.4
         */
        do_action( 'dokan_after_new_product_inside_content_area' );
    ?>

</div> <!-- #primary .content-area -->

<?php

    /**
     *  dokan_dashboard_content_after hook
     *  dokan_after_new_product_content_area hook
     *
     *  @since 2.4
     */
    do_action( 'dokan_dashboard_content_after' );
    do_action( 'dokan_after_new_product_content_area' );
?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edit this file public_html/wp-content/plugins/dokan-lite/classes/template-products.php

```
do_action( 'dokan_new_product_added', $product_id, $post_data );

                    if ( current_user_can( 'dokan_edit_product' ) ) {
                        $redirect = dokan_edit_product_url( $product_id );
               } else {
                        $redirect = dokan_get_navigation_url( 'products' );
                    }
```

Just replace the value for $redirect with your custom url like below

```
$redirect = ("https://www.wordpress.com/dashboard/products/");
```

For redirection after Edit product page replace the same below

```
do_action( 'dokan_product_updated', $post_id );

            //$edit_url = dokan_edit_product_url( $post_id );

            $redirect = apply_filters( 'dokan_add_new_product_redirect', dokan_edit_product_url( $post_id ), $post_id );

            wp_redirect( add_query_arg( array( 'message' => 'success' ), $redirect ) );
            exit;
```

Comment: You should not recommend making changes directly to the plugin itself, use filters/hooks instead. This change will be removed upon next plugin update.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to functions.php of your child theme.

At first, we remove default ajax action, then add our custom action with the same function, but with modified $redirect value.

```
if ( wp_doing_ajax() ) {
    remove_action( 'wp_ajax_dokan_create_new_product', array( 'WeDevs\Dokan\Ajax', 'create_product' ) );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_dokan_create_new_product', 'dokan_ajax_create_product' );
}
function dokan_ajax_create_product() {
    check_ajax_referer( 'dokan_reviews' );

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'dokan_add_product' ) ) {
        wp_send_json_error( __( 'You have no permission to do this action', 'dokan-lite' ) );
    }

    $submited_data = isset( $_POST['postdata'] ) ? wp_unslash( $_POST['postdata'] ) : ''; //phpcs:ignore

    parse_str( $submited_data, $postdata );

    $response = dokan_save_product( $postdata );

    if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
        wp_send_json_error( $response->get_error_message() );
    }

    if ( is_int( $response ) ) {
        /* if ( current_user_can( 'dokan_edit_product' ) ) {
            $redirect = dokan_edit_product_url( $response );
        } else { */
            $redirect = dokan_get_navigation_url( 'products' );
        /* } */

        wp_send_json_success( $redirect );
    } else {
        wp_send_json_error( __( 'Something wrong, please try again later', 'dokan-lite' ) );
    }
}
```

And, for non-ajax requests:

```
add_action( 'dokan_add_new_product_redirect', 'custom_dokan_add_new_product_redirect', 10, 2 );
function custom_dokan_add_new_product_redirect( $redirect, $product_id ) {
    $redirect = dokan_get_navigation_url( 'products' );
    return $redirect;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the new version of Dokan, you can adjust this in file dokan-lite/includes/Dashboard/Templates with the code above!